# Liferay: RememberMe not working

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, liferay-6

I'm using liferay 6.1.1 and I'm trying to put the rememeberMe functionality to work but without success. Tries every suggestion I could found.

I have the right config:

> company.security.auto.login=true
> company.security.auto.login.max.age=1209600
> session.enable.persistent.cookies=true

also tried:

> auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.RememberMeAutoLogin

All the cookies exist with the right expiration date:

> name GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID | value en_US | expires 23-04-2014 10:23:35
>
> name COOKIE_SUPPORT | value true | expires 22-04-2014 18:57:13
>
> name LOGIN | value ... | expires 07-05-2013 10:23:35
>
> name PASSWORD | value ... | expires 07-05-2013 10:23:35
>
> name REMEMBER_ME | value true | expires 07-05-2013 10:23:35
>
> name SCREEN_NAME | value ... | expires 07-05-2013 10:23:35
>
> name COMPANY_ID | value ... | expires 07-05-2013 10:23:35
>
> name ID | value ... | expires 07-05-2013 10:23:35
>
> name USER_UUID | value ... | expires 07-05-2013 10:23:35

Any thoughts? Hope you can help me.
Thank you.

Comment: do you mean the 'Rememeber Me' checkbox in the login form ? You can't see the checkbox , or it doesn't work ? Are you using some hook for the login ?

Comment: I can see the check box and I check it (and thus the REMEMBER_ME cookie) but if I close the browser and come back again, the password is requested again (the username/screenname is already there, so I believe it's getting it from the cookie).
I think it's using a hook for the login (I'm nem in Liferay). How can I be sure?

Comment: right, I didn't see the REMEMBER_ME cookie :) . Can you check with another browser and see if it works ?

Comment: doesn't work.
I checked the logs and I get several of these with different paths:
> 14:15:40,561 DEBUG [http-bio-18080-exec-6][AutoLoginFilter:174] [http-bio-18080-exec-6]< com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter /web/guest/home 399 ms

Comment: about the login hook, how can that impact this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the cause: a liferay bug (http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-29218).

Changing

> live.users.enabled=true

to

> live.users.enabled=false

solved it.